# React router dom does not render a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've faced a problem that my `<App>` component doesn't render a `<Route>` when clicking on `<Link>`.

I need to go to the `"admin/users/:1/userTrans"` URL (:1 is id here) by clicking the `<Link>` but when my URL changes, nothing happens, though, it looks like being correct.

I tried `location.pathname` and `history.push` but situation hasn't changed.

Below is my `<App>` component:

```jsx
const App = () => {
    const pathBase = '/admin';
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Tabbar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={`${pathBase}/users/`} component={AllUsers} />

                <Route path={`${pathBase}/users/:id`} component={DriverPage}/>

                <Route path={`${pathBase}/users/:1/userTrans`} component={UserTransactions}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/rides`} component={AllRides}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/chat`} component={AllMessages}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/userMessages`} component={UserMessages}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/mail`} component={Mailing}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/transactions`} component={AllTransactions}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/sales`} component={Sales}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/ads`} component={Ads}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/admins`} component={Admins}/>
                <Route path={`${pathBase}/stats`} component={Stats}/>
            </Switch>

        </div>  
    );
}
```

Below is a part of a component where `<Link>` is located:

```jsx
<Section classNames="transactions__section row">
    <h2 className="section__title">Transactions</h2>
    <div className="plates__wrapper">
        {userTransactions}
    </div>
    <Link to={{
        pathname: `${match.url}/userTrans`,
        state: {
            userId: params.id.substr(1)
        }
    }}>
        <Btn>All user transactions</Btn>
    </Link>
</Section>
```

Comment: `App` component is your root component?

Comment: ```index.js``` renders ```App``` on the page which contains everything.

Comment: Wrap your root component with a `BrowserRouter` possibly help.

Comment: You also might wanna add `exact` to all of your routes.

Answer (score 0):

You trying navigate to `users` path under `id` param with value `1`, so the URI should be one of:

```
${pathBase}/users/1/userTrans
${pathBase}/users?id=1/userTrans
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `exact` routes, I added `exact` to both main url and needed url.
So now it looks like:

```
<Route exact path={`${pathBase}/users/:id`} component={DriverPage}/>

<Route exact path={`${pathBase}/users/:1/userTrans`} component={UserTransactions}/>
```

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

You need to import BrowserRouter as Router from react-router-dom..
and wrap the Switch component with Router component.
it might look like this

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router,switch,Route } from react-router-dom;

 <Router>
<Switch>
Your routes here....
</Switch>
</Router>
```